# run a jquery function inside a div and not in the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, children

I'm working on a pretty simple html/jquery quiz. It will have multiple questions with multiple answers. Every time an answer (".question-option") is chosen inside a question (".question") it runs my jquery function.

The problem is that the results appears on the next question, the last in the DOM I guess, I wrapped my function inside an .each function but it's still not working properly...
here's a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ce1gtk9w/

```js
$(".question").each(function() {
  var question = $(this)
  questionOptionsAll = question.find($('.question-options'))
  questionOption = questionOptionsAll.find($('.question-option'))
  questionTrueFalse = question.find($('.answer-true-false'))
  questionOption.click(function() {
    questionOptionsAll.addClass('answered')
    var questionOptionSelected = $(this)
    if (questionOptionSelected.hasClass('correct')) {
      question.addClass('questions-correct')
      questionTrueFalse.text('correct !')
    } else if (!$(this).hasClass('correct')) {
      questionOptionSelected.addClass('uncorrect')
      question.addClass('questions-uncorrect')
      questionTrueFalse.text('Wrong !')
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.question {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.answer {
    display: none;
}

.question-options.answered li {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.questions-correct .answer {
    display: block;
}

.questions-correct .question-option.correct {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.questions-uncorrect .answer {
    display: block;
}

.questions-uncorrect .question-option.correct {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.question-option.uncorrect {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question" id="question-2">
  <div class="question-title">
    Question One
  </div>
  <ul class="question-options">
    <li class="question-option correct">2000</li>
    <li class="question-option">2012</li>
    <li class="question-option">2022</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="answer-true-false"></div>
  <div class="answer">Answer One.</div>
</div>
<div class="question" id="question-2">
  <div class="question-title">
    Question two
  </div>
  <ul class="question-options">
    <li class="question-option correct">2000</li>
    <li class="question-option">2012</li>
    <li class="question-option">2022</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="answer-true-false"></div>
  <div class="answer">Answer Two.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: You could also use the question's id and based on that, add only to that div the result: questionId = question.attr('id'), and then select the class inside this id to put the result

Answer (score 1):

Please delegate

NOTE I wrapped all questions in a div with ID questions

```js
$("#questions").on("click", ".question-option", function() {
  const $question = $(this).closest(".question");
  const $questionTrueFalse = $question.find('.answer-true-false');
  const correct = $(this).hasClass('correct');
  $question.toggleClass('questions-correct', correct)
  $questionTrueFalse.text(correct ? 'correct !' : 'Wrong !')
})
```

```css
.question {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.answer {
  display: none;
}

.question-options.answered li {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.questions-correct .answer {
  display: block;
}

.questions-correct .question-option.correct {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.questions-uncorrect .answer {
  display: block;
}

.questions-uncorrect .question-option.correct {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.question-option.uncorrect {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questions">
  <div class="question" id="question-1">
    <div class="question-title">
      Question One
    </div>
    <ul class="question-options">
      <li class="question-option correct">2000</li>
      <li class="question-option">2012</li>
      <li class="question-option">2022</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="answer-true-false"></div>
    <div class="answer">Answer One.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="question" id="question-2">
    <div class="question-title">
      Question two
    </div>
    <ul class="question-options">
      <li class="question-option correct">2000</li>
      <li class="question-option">2012</li>
      <li class="question-option">2022</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="answer-true-false"></div>
    <div class="answer">Answer Two.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cleaner than my answer, but note that you're missing the classes to highlight the red background on the wrong answers.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah man thanks I noticed